# Viewing Personal Geodatabase using software other than ArcGIS?

Tags: open-source-gis, personal-geodatabase

Is it possible to open a Personal Geodatabase file in software other than ArcGIS?

i.e are there any open source software available just for viewing the data?

Answer (score 14):

It can be viewed in [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/), a popular open source desktop gis application.

Choose `Layer > Add Vector Layer` and select Personal Geodatabase from File Types.

It will display all feature classes. But advanced ESRI features like Network and Topology will not be visible.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can open a PGDB in Microsoft Access if you have it as it's just an access database.

If you need opensource then you could use [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html)

Comment: Note that this will allow you to view the tabular data, but you will not be able to see the feature geometries.

Comment: You should also be careful to keep a backup of your personal geodatabase before doing this. While Access is a great way to peek into the database, and even make changes, you can easily kill your database if you edit the wrong table

Answer (score 3):

The free [TatukGIS viewer](http://www.tatukgis.com/Products/EditorViewer.aspx) will open ESRI personal geodatabases. It is not open source.

Comment: Thanks. Seems perfect for the times I just need to quickly view a file.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, as you mentioned just being able to view the files only. You could try exporting to a layer package file.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000013000000

The layer package derived from personal databases or layers contained therein, can be viewed in free software like ArcGIS Explorer (http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer-desktop/download).

This is useful if people need to view files, but do not have access to an ArcGIS Licence.

I don't know if that is exactly what you needed. But, hopefully the information is useful.